# Bootstrap toggle collapse - keep form open until clicking toggle button again

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a registration form that contains 2 parts where the user can input information, but I want them to be collapsible. Currently I have been able to make the forms open and close. A forms open when a button is clicked, but then when you click anywhere else on the page, it closes again.

**To clarify:** Form opens when upon button click, closes upon clicking anywhere else which is a pain because you cant select an input box as the form closes as soon as you click anywhere else.

> How do you go about making the collapse toggle remain true until you click the button again?

**Code:**

```
<head>
...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
...
</head>
<body>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form role="form" action="<?=admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>" method="post" id="register-form" autocomplete="off">
        <div>
            <h4>User Info</h4>
                <span class="btn reg-org pull-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#user_info">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                </span>
            <div id="user_info" class="collapse">

            //FORM CONTENT

            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <h4>Further Info</h4>
                <span class="btn reg-org pull-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#further_info">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                </span>
            <div id="further_info" class="collapse">

            //FORM CONTENT

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Am I missing something obvious? I'm fairly new to this but I couldn't get anything I found online to work.

Comment: hi, could you write a jsfiddle?

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to say but it should work fine. The one thing only is coming to my mind. Maybe you have something wrong with your CSS.

Maybe you are badly positioning this button that it's area cover whole div `#user_info`
Try to check this under developer tools.

I am putting this code and it works fine regardless that buttons are positioning so badly.

If you need the solution `that makes div beeing still collapsed even while clicking the button again` i have put the answer to this question here

[Keeping an uncollapsed element open if it's parent is clicked on again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714317/keeping-an-uncollapsed-element-open-if-its-parent-is-clicked-on-again?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
target = $(this).data('target');
if($(target).is(':visible')){
    return false;
}
});
```