# Keeping an uncollapsed element open if it's parent is clicked on again

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

First of all apologies for the terrible wording, I'm having trouble describing the issue.

Currently I have a series of buttons in a horizontal row, whereby clicking on a button shows it's associated content underneath, and clicking on a different button collapses the current content and shows the new content (using the 'data-parent' attribute). I want it to function so that for example, if button 3 is clicked and it's content shown, and the user then clicks on button 3 again, instead of the content collapsing I would like it to remain on screen. The way it works currently is that if button 3's content is shown and button 3 is clicked again, the element collapses and we're just left with a row of buttons again. I've experimented with the '.collapse("show")' method but I'm having difficulty implementing it (not even sure if it's possible to work with this method). Here is the associated code:

```
<div class ="container" id="content">

    <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#0" data-parent="#content">0</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#1" data-parent="#content">1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#2" data-parent="#content">2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#3" data-parent="#content">3</button>

    <div class="panel">
        <div id="0" class="collapse in">
            Button 0's content
        </div>

        <div id="1" class="collapse">
            Button 1's content    
        </div>

        <div id="2" class="collapse">
            Button 2's content    
        </div>

        <div id="3" class="collapse">
            Button 3's content    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share the js code you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know if this solution will satisfy you but you can block this like that

for example

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
target = $(this).data('target');
if($(target).is(':visible')){
    return false;
}
});
```

In this situation if you click on "button1" it will collapse the correct div and if you click this again nothing will happen. However clicking another button will collapse another div.